# Accessing the "statuses/sample" Twitter API in Tweepy

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I've been using the Tweepy streaming library to get tweets. It doesn't download very many tweets very quickly. I tried the cURL command for [GET statuses/sample](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/sample), and it gives me a lot more. But I don't see a method to access this anywhere in the [Tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html).

Is there any way to do this with Tweepy? I'd rather not have to deal with the OAuth and everything myself.

Answer (score 5):

Aha. It's not in the documentation, but in the source, I found that I can use `Stream.sample` instead of `Stream.filter` like in the docs.